# Как здес правильно исползовать each?

Tags: jquery, динамическое-программирование

Create кнопку с динамическим методом, чтобы создать 10 погружений и разместить страницу в разных точках
Измените гигантские координаты на каждые 500 миллисекунд и дайте им случайный шанс
При прохождении Transition окажется, что divi движутся в случайных направлениях
Стоп клик на каждом слайдере

```
<body>
<button id="create">Create</button>
</body>


$(document).ready(function() {
    var start
    $("#create").click(function() {

            $("#b1").empty()
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var div = $("<div></div>")
            div.addClass("divan")
            let r = parseInt(Math.random()*256)
            let g = parseInt(Math.random()*256)
            let b = parseInt(Math.random()*256)
            let color = `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`
            let top = parseInt(Math.random()*500)
            let left = parseInt(Math.random()*1000)
            let width = parseInt(Math.random()*(500-300)+200)
            let height = parseInt(Math.random()*(500-300)+200)
            div.css({
                width: width,
                height: height,
                border: "1px solid",
                display: "inline-block",
                position: "absolute",
                background: color,
                top: top,
                left: left,

            });
            $("#b1").append(div)
        }
    });
    if ($(".divan")) {
        $(".divan").each(function(e){
            start = setInterval(function() {


            let top = parseInt(Math.random()*500)
            let left = parseInt(Math.random()*1000)
            $(this).css({
                // top: top,
                // left: left,
                transition: "2s"        
            });

        // $(this).click(function() {
        //  clearInterval(start)
        // });
            },500)
    })
}
});
```

Comment: Дайте ссылку или внесите в вопрос условие Вашей задачи на оригинальном английском. Я переведу. Ваш перевод, к сожалению, совсем никакой.

Comment: Спасибо я уже нашел ответ)